# Mute/unmute role that removes/gives back all roles

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to mute someone, and that person has some roles. Using the mute command would remove all roles from that person, then give them a mute role. The unmute role would do the same, once you unmute the person they get all their roles back.

Comment: What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a basic command handler set up, here is some basic functionality you can use:

```js
const member = message.mentions.members.first()
if (!member) return;
member.roles.add('<muted role ID>')
```

And for an unmute command you can do the same sort of thing:

```js
member.roles.remove('<muted role ID>')
```

---

> Using the mute command would remove all roles from that person...
> Once you unmute the person they get all their roles back...

This would be very hard to execute, as there's not an easy way to store what roles the member had before they were muted. Instead, you can just set the `Muted` role's permissions to be of higher priority than the others.